# Calculating the volume of a magnetic field emitted from a superconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

Given the magnetic field strength of a magnetic field generated by a superconductor, how could you calculate the total volume that this field encompasses?

The main reason I'm asking this question is as superconductors exclude magnetic fields from its interior, I'm wondering how this changes anything in the process of calculating the volume of a magnetic field.

Comment: How do you define the "volume" of the magnetic field?

Comment: An Area of space occupied by the magnetic field. The purpose of finding the volume is to calculate the energy stored in a magnetic field. I came down to the B^2/2uo calculation but you have to integrate this value over unit volume @ThePhoton

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the magnetic field near a long wire? Does it ever go to zero, if you get far enough away from the wire?

Comment: How does this work in a setup of multiple adjacent coils? @ThePhoton

Comment: Google the *Biot-Savart Law*.